# Can I reserve a bus pass from Shinjuku to the Fuji Shibazakura Festival?

Tags: japan, bookings, buses

Per [this](http://bus-en.fujikyu.co.jp/highway/detail/id/1/#routemap) site as best I can tell there are 2 buses that go from Shinjuku to the Fuji Shibazakura festival. One leaves at 7:35 and one leaves at 8:45 (please confirm if my interpretation is correct). I would like to make a reservation for the 7:35 one. There is a reservation link at the bottom of the page that goes to [here](https://www.highwaybus.com/rs-web01-prd-rel/gp/foreign/frgSelectLine?lang=en).

This reservation page is not particularly helpful though... As best I can tell there is no way to reserve a ticket to/from the festival there.

Is there any way to reserve such a bus ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...I looked at the Japanese language version of the page. It also had a reservation link, which tooked me to [this](https://www.highwaybus.com/gp/reservation/rsvPlanList?lineId=110) page, which is a functioning ticket reservation website. So, the answer is: yes, you can reserve a bus ticket to the Fuji Shibazakura Festival. However, it seems that the reservation site is available in Japanese only, and you are in poor luck if you couldn't read Japanese.

You could try calling the Fujikyuko Tokyo area bus sales center at 03-3376-1229, and hope that they have someone who speaks English (and I think they should). I remember that they also have a ticket office in the Shinjuku Bus Terminal, so you may also go there and ask if you are currently in Tokyo.

Comment: You may want to change that number to +813-3376-1229 for those who are intending to call from overseas.